# How to set http header Cache?

Tags: php

I need to store the javascript and page details to browser cache using http headers.

Can anyone help me to get this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTML meta:

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">`

**or**

PHP headers:

```
header("Cache-Control: public"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the future
```

*Source: [[PHP Manual]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)*

Comment: Setting the expire date in the past will force the browser to reload the resource - quite the opposite of caching..

Comment: Sorry about that. Read the wrong part of the manual, not too familiar with headers.

Comment: your answer now appears to be correct. Please take care when answering question to read it properly. Also only copy-pasting from the documentation doesn't really constitute a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply setting the expire date in a header -

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the future
```

It should be noted that modern browsers do a good job caching resources. Usually these methods are used to force reloading a resource; To prevent browser cache.

Comment: I have used the same code which you have posted here, But I am getting below result and its not working,    [HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => no-cache

Comment: How are you referencing the JavaScript file?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand what you mean exactly here.... I referenced the javascript file through script tag...

Comment: Well there is the confusion. What you are setting here is the cache control for the HTML page that is being loaded. If you want to set specific headers for specific files you might have to manually send your JavaScript file through PHP.

Comment: Just I have added the two line which posted by you with post expired date.. is there anything I need to add before? Thanks for your patience and timely help.. I tried other ways like using metatag... But its not worked out

Comment: I think there is a little bit of confusion as to what exactly you are wanting to cache. I've added another answer that should clear this up. I'm going to delete *this* answer shortly as my second one also covers the same ground

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion about exactly what you are wanting to cache. Two items are being referred to here -

1. The page itself with all HTML elements and references to external files.
2. A JavaScript file being referenced to by the HTML document.

To cache the first item (the page), setting the headers with PHP should cache the HTML contents of the page.

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Expires: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 00:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the future
```

This will cache the contents of the page but not necessarily the files referenced by it. For example, if you had in your HTML file this code -

```
<script src="http://domain/some/js/file.js" type="javascript" ></script>
```

Then that **text** will be caches but not `file.js`. To manually set the cache on those external files, you'll need to serve them using PHP and manually set the headers.
You'll want to do something similar to this -

```
<script src="another_file.php" type="javascript" ></script>
```

Now in `another_file.php` you are going to want to load the JavaScript file and "echo" it out with the appropriate headers -

```
$file = '/absolute/path/to/your_script.js';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit();
}
```